# How to use sqlx query_as to fetch some of the model fields

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have a table called `order_data` which has `timestamp` field called `created_on` and `i32` field `order_id`. I want to query those in different methods.
For `created_on`:

```
pub async fn fetch_last_created_on(pool: &Pool<Postgres>) -> Option<NaiveDateTime> {
    let result = match query_as::<Postgres, OrderDb>("select max(created_on) as created_on from order_data")
        .fetch_one(pool)
        .await
    {
        Ok(result) => result.created_on,
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Error fetching data: {}", e);
            None
        }
    };
    result
}
```

And for `order_id`:

```
pub async fn fetch_all_order_ids(pool: &Pool<Postgres>) -> Option<HashSet<i32>> {
    let result = match query_as::<Postgres, OrderDb>("select order_id from order_data")
        .fetch_all(pool)
        .await
    {
        Ok(result) => Some(result.iter().map(|order| order.order_id.unwrap()).collect()),
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Error fetching data: {}", e);
            None
        }
    };

    result
}
```

I've defined `OrderDb` as:

```
#[derive(FromRow)]
struct OrderDb {
    order_id: Option<i32>,
    created_on: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
}
```

But with this if use `fetch_last_created_on` it results in the following error

> no column found for name: order_id

I could define two separate `derive(FromRow)` structs for each case, but is there a better way to handle it?
Do note that I'm not using macros but methods.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in sqlx, but you probably want `query_as::<_, (NaiveDateTime,)>(...` or similar if you're expecting rows with only a single timestamp column.

Comment: @kmdreko tried that, but `the trait for<'r> FromRow<'r, PgRow> is not implemented for NaiveDateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. There are different techniques to be used.
For `created_on`:

```
pub async fn fetch_last_created_on(pool: &Pool<Postgres>) -> Option<NaiveDateTime> {
    let result: (Option<NaiveDateTime>, ) = query_as("select max(created_on) from order_data")
        .fetch_one(pool)
        .await
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            error!("Couldn't fetch data! {}", e);
            (None, )
        });

    result.0
}
```

And for `order_id` (note, that I've changed the return type from `HashSet` to `Vec`):

```
pub async fn fetch_all_order_ids(pool: &Pool<Postgres>) -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
    return match query_scalar("select order_id from order_data")
        .fetch_all(pool)
        .await {
        Ok(order_ids) => {
            Some(order_ids)
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Couldn't fetch order ids! {}", e);
            None
        }
    };
}
```

As a side note, one could also implement it in a way to return `Result` instead of `Option`. I prefer to handle errors in a place where they occur, thus I transform `Result` into `Option` here

Answer (score 1):

You can put `#[sqlx(default)]` for `order_id` and `created_on` in your struct. With that, if you do not select the field in your query, the default value would be used (for `Option`, default would be `None`)

```rust
#[derive(FromRow)]
struct OrderDb {
    #[sqlx(default)]
    order_id: Option<i32>,
    #[sqlx(default)]
    created_on: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
}
```

see: https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html#default

Answer (score -2):

You may need to create new struct for this and you can map to Tags

```
// original struct 
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow)]
pub struct Tags {
    pub uuid: Option<Uuid>,
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub created_at: Option<DateTime<chrono::Utc>>,
}


// this struct to get only uuid from sql
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow)]
pub struct TestTags {
    pub uuid: Uuid,
}

pub async fn exists(
    name: String, 
    conn: &mut PgConnection,
) -> Result<Tags, sqlx::Error> {
    let query_str = r#"
    SELECT uuid FROM tags
    WHERE name = $1
    "#;
    let tag = sqlx::query_as
        ::<_, TestTags>(query_str)
            .bind(name)
            .fetch_one(conn)
            .await
            .map(|tag| {
                Tags {uuid: tag.uuid, name: None, created_at: None}
            });
            // .map_err(|e| {
            //     OurError::from_sqlx_error(e)
            // });
    tag

}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but I didn't want to create a separate struct for each possible combination of fields